# new String(); in java

Tags: java, string, assert

I have an assert statement to check the equal method in a class. below is the 2 statements

```
Assert.assertTrue(a.equals(new VideoObj(title, year, director)));
Assert.assertTrue(a.equals(new VideoObj(new String(title), year, director)));
```

what is the difference in the two statements? and why does the 2nd assert statement have `new String(title)`, can someone tell me what is the difference in doing so?

And also could you provide with a tutorial for me to learn writing test class for Java?

thanks

Comment: We would have to see the constructor of VideoObj to know.

Comment: read this to learn about writing test classes for java http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/ant/ant_chap04.pdf

Comment: @PéterVarga - and the `equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If `title` is not a `String`, then the second assert statement might be invoking a different `VideoObj` constructor. Without more info about `title` and about the `VideoObj` class, it's hard to say more.

Do a web search for *junit tutorial* to get lots of resources for learning how to write test classes.

**EDIT** From your comment to the answer by @BrianRoach, I gather that your `VideoObj.equals(Object)` method is implemented as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object thatObject) {
    if (!(thatObject instanceof VideoObj)) return false;
    VideoObj that = (VideoObj) thatObject;
    return ((_title.equals(that.title()))
        || (_director.equals(that.director()))
        || (_year == that.year()));
}
```

If that's right, then the problem is that your `return` statement should be using `&&` instead of `||` operators. That would explain why your asserts are not complaining.

Comment: @anisha - I updated my answer based on your comment to Brian Roach.

Answer (score 1):

new String() explicitly creates a new object of String.
And:

```
Assert.assertTrue(a.equals(new VideoObj(title, year, director)));
```

reuses existing String object (which can give you different results depending on equals method implementation in `VideoObj`), or uses some other object like `byte[]` as there is a constructor for `new String(byte[])`. Of course there are many others (see Java API).

...edit
Check this out:

```
String s1=new String("abcxyz");
String s2=new String("abc"+"xyz");
String s3=s1+s2;
String s4="abcxyz";    // string literal will go to string pool
String s5="abc"+"xyz"; // string literal will go to string pool

System.out.println(s1==s2);
System.out.println(s2==s3);
System.out.println(s3==s4);
System.out.println(s4==s5); // TRUE (the rest are false)
System.out.println(s2==s4);
System.out.println(s2==s5);
System.out.println(s3==s1);
System.out.println(s3==s5);
```

Comment: `title` could also be a `char[]`, a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer`. There are single-argument `String` constructors for each of those types as well.

Comment: ok, got it 
but i have an assert statement like

String title = "A";
  int year = 2009;
  String director = "Zebra";

  VideoObj a = new VideoObj(title, year, director);


  Assert.assertTrue(a.equals(new VideoObj(title, year, director)));
how does this test pass?it is something like System.out.println(s1==s2); right??
could you please explain???
thanks

Comment: No, when you are passing `title`, you are not creating new string object. So if your `VideoObj` `equals` method uses something like `if (this.title == obj.title) ...` then it is able to return TRUE, while with `new String(title)` it will return false. When you use `title` it is like s4==s5, and when you use `new String(title)` it's like s1==s2.

Answer (score 1):

The new String() statement creates a new String object with the content of the original String. That gives you two String objects (the original one and the one that was newly created with the new String(originalString) statement)  that have equal content, but are two different Java objects. If you compare these two objects with the == operator, this comparison will return false, because it's two different objects. Whereas a comparison with the String's equals() method will still return true, because these two strings have the same text stored inside them.

So I assume the intention of this assertion in the test is to make sure that the equals() method of "a" really uses the equals() method of the title string to check for equality, and does not just do a simple == comparison of the two title strings. Without that assertion, such an invalid implementation of a's equals() method could remain unnoticed because the two title strings in the compared object could be references to the same String object, which would then also give you the expected result when using the (wrong) == operator to test them for equality.

Comment: ok got it.
so in == for object it will return false and for Strings it will return true.
so the assertion that i wrote checks whether it is using equal() in the equal method in the videoObj.
if the equal method in the VideoObj has ==, it will test if i didn't send in a object as new String(title);
Am i correct??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference is this:

If in `VideoObj`'s the `equals()` method has been overridden and is using the `String` that is passed in via the constructor as `title`, it's checking to make sure it works if the `String` isn't a *literal*

If in `equals()` someone did this:

```
...
if (otherObj.getTitle() == this.title) {
...
```

The first assertion would succeed while the second would fail if `title` was a string literal. String literals in Java are interned into a pool meaning that you end up with multiple references to the same literal if it's used multiple times;

```
String a = "This is a string";
String b = "This is a string";
// a and b will both be the same reference
String c = new String("This is a string");
// c will *not* be the same reference
```

**Edit:** Note this is assuming that `title` in your first assertion is indeed a `String`

Comment: what is a string literal?
the VideoObj equal has overriden as below

public boolean equals(Object thatObject) {
  if (!(thatObject instanceof VideoObj))
   return false;
  VideoObj that = (VideoObj) thatObject;
  return ((_title.equals(that.title())) || (_director.equals(that.director())) || (_year == that.year()));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Java does some optimization. If you have two strings with the same value it is most probably the same object. This can be done because strings are immutable. But if you explicitly create a new String with a constructor call, a new object is created.

Comment: This is ... not exactly correct. String *literals* are interned.

Comment: That's what I meant. If you create strings by literals, same values are mapped to the same object. If you create them by constructor call, they aren't.

Comment: Well, write what you meant then :) It has nothing to do with the fact that `String` objects (literals and non-literals) are immutable, nor does it really have anything to do with the value of the `String` when talking about literal vs. non-literal.

Comment: I guess my explanation was a little short and shallow. Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries - just trying to provide some feedback; I didn't mean for it to sound rude or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between the 2 statements, provided that 'title' is a String.

Comment: This assumes that `title` is a `String` object.

Comment: There is actually a case where those two statements could produce different results even if `title` is a `String`. If inside the `VideoObj`'s `equals()` someone did the silly thing of comparing the Strings using `==` and `title` is a string literal.

Comment: @Ted: yes, hence the "provided that".

Answer (score 0):

`title` can either be a `String`, a `StringBuffer`, a `StringBuilder`, a `char[]` or a `byte[]`. If it's a String, it'll run the same constructor as the other call, but in all other cases it may run a totally different, overloaded, constructor.

Without seeing the type of `title`, it's impossible to tell which.

Edit: Since the type is String, the reason for the new String is most likely to make sure that the underlying code does not compare strings using == (reference-equals) by mistake. If it did, the first test may pass (string constants with the same value may indeed reference the same String object and the test may use constants for setup and test) while the second one would break since == would no longer match with a freshly created String.